# Which algorithm is best to traverse weighted , directed graph provided the start and end point?

Tags: data-structures, graph

Hi I am looking for the best algorithm to find out the optimal path traversing a directed and weighted graph.

[Hi all, I am editing the problem for explaining my requirement completely]

e.g: If in a graph of 5 nodes (let's assign number 1,2,3,4,5 to all the 5 nodes respectively), if I wish to start traversing from node 2 and end up at 4 , covering all the nodes, then which is the best algorithm to solve the problem ?

We can have two assumptions :

a) There is always an edge between any two nodes. (means for two nodes (A and B) there is an edge from A to B and from B to A as well.

b) we can traverse a node twice (If necessary to traverse complete graph).

Comment: No , graph does not have any negative edge. But I want the algorithm to traverse all the nodes and end up at particular node.

Comment: Like In a graph of 5 nodes (let's assign number 1,2,3,4,5 to all the 5 nodes respectively), if I wish to start traversing from node 2 and end up at 4 , covering all the nodes, then which is the best algorithm to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 6):

This is a classical problem in computer science with a well-known solution.

Do the graphs have non-negative edge weights only? Then use [Dĳkstra’s algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) or [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*). Otherwise use the [Bellman–Ford algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm). If you want to find *all* pairs of shortest paths between all nodes, use the [algorithm of Floyd & Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm).

Comment: Does Dijkstra's algorithm will also serve the purpose of ending at some desired node.
Like In a graph of 5 nodes (let's assign number 1,2,3,4,5 to all the 5 nodes respectively), if I wish to start traversing from node 2 and  
end up at 4 , covering all the nodes, then will Dijkstra algorithm serve the purpose ?

Comment: @AbhishekGahlout No, the algorithm will *not* cover that. You didn’t mention the requirement “cover all nodes” explicitly before (I took “traverse” to mean just get across it). It sounds like what you are searching is a minimal tour, kind of like TSP – does this thread maybe help? [Minimum cost closed walk in a graph](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/13267) (Incidentally, this additional information makes your problem much more complex and interesting).

Comment: Yeah !! This additional information makes the problem much more complex and interesting too. Thanks for the link. This link talks about the related problem (to my problem) but for undirected graph.

Answer (score 2):

Using Dijkstra is the way to go, but you can tweak the algorithm (which by default is a single source - multiple sink algorithm) to be a single-source single-sink implementation.

Basically instead of starting with one node (the source node) start with both the start and end nodes at the same time. For the sink nodes traverse the edges in reverse direction.
You can use two priority queues and for each step peak which queue to remove the next entry from. Whenever you are trying to enqueue a new element, check whether it is already contained in the other queue. In this case you have found a path from the source to the sink.